# Wrap every 2 divs in row - for each loop

Tags: loop, php

For some reason, having a bit of a nightmare wrapping every 2 divs in a row in this for each loop....

Could anyone shed any light on it at all?

```
                <?php 
                    $terms = get_terms("aircraft_category"); // get all categories
                    $count = count($terms); //Count how many terms we have

                    if ( $count > 0 ){  //If there are more than 0 terms
                        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {  //for each term:
                            echo "<div class='col-md-6 category'>";
                            echo "<h3>";
                            echo $term->name;
                            echo "</h3>";
                            echo $term->description;
                            echo "<div class='link'>";
                            echo "<a href=".get_term_link($term).">" . 'See More' . "</a>";
                            echo "</div>";
                            echo " </div>\n";

                            //create a list item with the current term slug for sorting, and name for label
                        }
                    } 
                ?>
```

I've tried adding counters, but had no success...

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is plain PHP, not WordPress specific. And we have covered it a thousand times on our site already. Please use our fine search before you ask a question. :)

Comment: Hi Toscho - I wouldnt say this is off topic, but I suppose, as it suggests, whats on and off topic is not always intuitive... I struggled to find a correct 'Answer' among the thousands that you have mentioned, so I decided to ask the question.

Comment: You have an array and want to create different depending each element's index. This is just PHP, there is no WordPress in the problem.Where the array is coming from doesn't affect the problem or its solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a variable with the count and then check against it e.g.

```
$num = 1;
foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
 if($num%2) {
  echo '<div class="something">';
 }

 // other stuff

 if($num %2) {
  echo '</div>';
 }
 $num++
}
```

The %2 is the part you need, it checks whether the number is dividable by 2

Comment: You somewhere are going to have an odd amount of terms, meaning you are going to have an open div, which is going to break your html